# Converting a date from long format to LocalDateTime format in Java 8

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time, localdate

I'm using java 8 and i have a method that accepts a date in long format parameter and returns a date in `LocalDateTime` from `java.time.LocalDateTime` library.

Before with java versions < 8, I used `java.util.Date` but now I need to use the `java.time.LocalDateTime` but I can't find documentation on how to convert from `long` value to `LocalDateTime`.

Before:

```java
public Date setDate (long ldate){

  Date newDate = new Date(ldate);

  return newDate;
}
```

Now:

```java
public LocalDateTime setDate(long ldate){

  LocalDateTime newDate;

  //{convert from long to LocalDateTime}

  return newDate
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ernest_k i think this might be what i'm looking for, will you please explain what is the Epoch time?

Comment: Check this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time (in your case, `ldate` is the number of milliseconds since Epoch)

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class for this. Read its class JavaDoc. For a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the method like this how LocalDateTime:

```java
public LocalDateTime setDate(long ldate){

        Date dateLong = new Date(ldate);    
        Instant instant = dateLong.toInstant();
        ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = instant.atZone(defaultZoneId).toLocalDateTime();
        return localDateTime;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to mix the terrible legacy class `Date` with the modern *java.time* classes. See the `Instant.ofEpoch…` methods.

Comment: The `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class here. That class discards the valuable time zone information. Use `ZonedDateTime` instead.